# atoi() for int128_t type

Tags: c++, c, int

How can I use `argv` values with `int128_t` support? I know about `atoi()` and family of functions exposed by `<cstdlib>` but somehow I cannot find one for `int128_t` fixed width integer. This might be because of the fact that this `type` isn't backed by either c or c++ standard, but is there any way for me to make this code work?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    __int128_t value = atoint128_t(argv[1]);
}
```

---

*Almost all answers posted are good enough for me but I'm selecting the one that is a drop by solution for my current code, so do look at other ones too.*

Comment: what's the sizeof intmax_t?

Comment: What about implementing your own `atoint128_t` ? Once the 128 bit integer becomes part of the standard, you will switch your implementation to a wrapper calling standard function.

Comment: I doubt there is a function available. Try writing your own implementation. A quick google search revealed something: https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/master/c%2B%2B/src/Int128.cc#L355 - Otheriwse you can take a look at some of the Big Integer libraries available. Although I am not a fan of recommending libraries, you might want to take a look at one.

Comment: In C11 if something like `int128_t` exists then `intmax_t` should cover it... (but yeah, it doesn't, there is `__int128_t`...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the size of `intmax_t` is `8` while `__int128_t` is `16`.

Comment: @Marian that's the plan ahead, just looking for alternatives :)

Comment: atoi() is already bad by design since it doesn't use error handling. What you are looking for is rather `strtolll`, if there existed such a type as `long long long`.

Comment: [Convert string to __uint128_t using stringstreams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26700672/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a C++ implementation:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

__int128_t atoint128_t(std::string const & in)
{
    __int128_t res = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    bool sign = false;

    if (in[i] == '-')
    {
        ++i;
        sign = true;
    }

    if (in[i] == '+')
    {
        ++i;
    }

    for (; i < in.size(); ++i)
    {
        const char c = in[i];
        if (not std::isdigit(c)) 
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Non-numeric character: ") + c)
        res *= 10;
        res += c - '0';
    }

    if (sign)
    {
        res *= -1;
    }

    return res;
}

int main()
{
  __int128_t a = atoint128_t("170141183460469231731687303715884105727");
}
```

If you want to test it then there is a stream operator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25115163/2378300).

**Performance**

I ran a few performance test. I generate 100,000 random numbers uniformly distributed in the entire support of `__int128_t`. Then I converted each of them 2000 times. All of these (200,000,000) conversions where completed within ~12 seconds.
Using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 gen(0);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> num(0, 9);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> len(1, 38);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> sign(0, 1);

    std::vector<std::string> str;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        std::string s;
        int l = len(gen);
        if (sign(gen))
            s += '-';
        for (int u = 0; u < l; ++u)
            s += std::to_string(num(gen));
        str.emplace_back(s);
    }

    namespace sc = std::chrono;
    auto start =  sc::duration_cast<sc::microseconds>(sc::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    __int128_t b = 0;
    for (int u = 0; u < 200; ++u)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
        {
            __int128_t a = atoint128_t(str[i]);
            b += a;
        }
    }
    auto time =  sc::duration_cast<sc::microseconds>(sc::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() - start;
    std::cout << time / 1000000. << 's' << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @Jonas Paul R actually meant that you are missing all negative numbers here. eg `-12` is still a valid `__int128_t`

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I realised that just after putting in my comment (hence I deleted it). And I have now updated my example.

Comment: Thanks for adding support for negative values. You might also want to skip over any leading white space (see the initial `while` loop in @FelixPalmen's answer).

Comment: @PaulR I'll look into it. Do you know the 'price' of calling `std::string::c_str`? I would like to verify the performance issues @FelixPalmen mentions, but at the moment I simply cannot. I use `std::string::c_str` to call the function designed by @FelixPalmen.

Comment: @Jonas it's easy to factor out if you create a *second* vector containing the C strings. That said, the real performance could be quite fine if the target CPU supports multiplying at least 64bit numbers, while my approach suffers from the fact I can't use "hardware carries" in C, therefore wasting time on checking single bits. So for "only" 128 bit, there's a good chance your "naive" approach is faster. The larger the numbers get, though -- you know ;)

Comment: @Jonas I'll add that to my answer, so it doesn't look like trying to "discredit" the naive approach.

Comment: You should check for integer overflow.

Comment: Corner case: when converting the minimum `__int128_t` or `"-170141183460469231731687303715884105728"`, `res += c - '0';` overflows signed integer math, even though the final result is in range.  This UB is usually as desired, but it is not defined.

Comment: I am sad to see this code get more votes than carefully honed C versions.  I guess a java or a javascript version would be even more rewarded.

Comment: @chqrlie the Q is double tagged and I see nothing wrong with a *straight forward* C++ approach. The code here might serve the purpose quite well in many cases. I personally just don't like the exception throwing...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I am not questioning the pertinence of C++ code, given the tags, and as it stands now, all answer are equally upvoted 3 times.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple way of implementing this:

```
__int128_t atoint128_t(const char *s)
{
    const char *p = s;
    __int128_t val = 0;

    if (*p == '-' || *p == '+') {
        p++;
    }
    while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
        val = (10 * val) + (*p - '0');
        p++;
    }
    if (*s == '-') val = val * -1;
    return val;
}
```

This code checks each character to see if it's a digit (with an optional leading + or -), and if so it multiplies the current result by 10 and adds the value associated with that digit.  It then inverts the sign if need be.

Note that this implementation does not check for overflow, which is consistent with the behavior of `atoi`.

EDIT:

Revised implementation that covers `int128_MIN` case by either adding or subtracting the value of each digit based on the sign, and skipping leading whitespace.

```
int myatoi(const char *s)
{
    const char *p = s;
    int neg = 0, val = 0;

    while ((*p == '\n') || (*p == '\t') || (*p == ' ') ||
           (*p == '\f') || (*p == '\r') || (*p == '\v')) {
        p++;
    }
    if ((*p == '-') || (*p == '+')) {
        if (*p == '-') {
            neg = 1;
        }
        p++;
    }
    while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
        if (neg) {
            val = (10 * val) - (*p - '0');
        } else {
            val = (10 * val) + (*p - '0');
        }
        p++;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Corner case UB with [int128_MIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608424/atoi-for-int128-t-type/45619499#comment78199007_45608851).  The usual UB is acceptable, but still UB.

Comment: @chux Good catch.  Revised to handle `int128_MIN`.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks.  Added that as well.

Comment: @dbush: `isspace((unsigned char)*p)` would be more efficient than a pack if 6 tests.

Answer (score 3):

Adding here a "not-so-naive" implementation in pure C, it's  still kind of simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

__int128 atoi128(const char *s)
{
    while (*s == ' ' || *s == '\t' || *s == '\n' || *s == '+') ++s;
    int sign = 1;
    if (*s == '-')
    {
        ++s;
        sign = -1;
    }
    size_t digits = 0;
    while (s[digits] >= '0' && s[digits] <= '9') ++digits;
    char scratch[digits];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < digits; ++i) scratch[i] = s[i] - '0';
    size_t scanstart = 0;

    __int128 result = 0;
    __int128 mask = 1;
    while (scanstart < digits)
    {
        if (scratch[digits-1] & 1) result |= mask;
        mask <<= 1;
        for (size_t i = digits-1; i > scanstart; --i)
        {
            scratch[i] >>= 1;
            if (scratch[i-1] & 1) scratch[i] |= 8;
        }
        scratch[scanstart] >>= 1;
        while (scanstart < digits && !scratch[scanstart]) ++scanstart;
        for (size_t i = scanstart; i < digits; ++i)
        {
            if (scratch[i] > 7) scratch[i] -= 3;
        }
    }

    return result * sign;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        __int128 x = atoi128(argv[1]);
        printf("%" PRIi64 "\n", (int64_t)x); // just for demo with smaller numbers
    }
}
```

It reads the number bit by bit, using a shifted BCD scratch space, see [Double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) for the algorithm (it's reversed here). This is a lot more efficient than doing many multiplications by 10 **in general**. *)

This relies on VLAs, without them, you can replace

```
char scratch[digits];
```

with

```
char *scratch = malloc(digits);
if (!scratch) return 0;
```

and add a

```
free(scratch);
```

at the end of the function.

Of course, the code above has the same limitations as the original `atoi()` (e.g. it will produce "random" garbage on overflow and has no way to check for that) .. if you need `strtol()`-style guarantees and error checking, extend it yourself (not a big problem, just work to do).

---

*)  Of course, implementing double dabble in C always suffers from the fact you can't use "hardware carries", so there are extra bit masking and testing operations necessary. On the other hand, "naively" multiplying by 10 **can** be very efficient, as long as the platform provides multiplication instructions with a width "close" to your target type. Therefore, on your typical `x86_64` platform (which has instructions for multiplying 64bit integers), this code is probably a lot slower than the naive decimal method. But it scales much better to really *huge* integers (which you would implement e.g. using arrays of `uintmax_t`).

Comment: `alloca()` is also an option if VLAs aren't available.  If `char scratch[digits];` is acceptable, `char *scratch = alloca( digits );` is also acceptable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `alloca()` isn't in any standard AFAIK. If it's available, VLAs are *probably* available as well, as long as it isn't a C89-only compiler.

Comment: Same corner issues [min_value UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608424/atoi-for-int128-t-type/45619499#comment78199007_45608851) and [+ sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608424/atoi-for-int128-t-type/45619499#comment78199062_45608851)

Comment: @chux + is accounted for. Min value isn't, if its absolute is larger than max value. That's not trivial, btw.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I now see the `'+'` at the end of the `while()`, yet this code now passes `"+++123"`, unlike `aoti()`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen BTW: not too hard to cope with the [min value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45619499/2410359) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45619917/2410359)

Comment: The skipping statement is incorrect: you should skip all characters that match `isspace()` and you should not skip multiple `+` signs nor `+` followed by whitespace or a `-`.

Comment: @chqrlie Depends on whether you need defined output on undefined input. My implementation is *partially correct* (read: *garbage in, garbage out*)

Comment: btw, I'm in the rare position to give an uv to *all* other answers as any of them somehow solve the problem and provide something to learn from :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: actually, `strtol("++1", NULL, 0)` is defined to return `0`, not `1` and `atoi()` is defined to return the same value as `strtol()` except for error handling, ie: if the conversion generates an overflow.

Comment: @chqrlie: maybe I should make clear this doesn't *exactly* mimic `atoi` behavior. `++1` is not a well-defined string representation of an integer. *partial correctness* means returning the correct value on any *valid* input, not caring for *invalid* input. Except for the corner case of min value with 2's complement, my function does that (and nothing more). Of course there's room for improvement :)

Comment: Thankyou for introducing me to Double Dabble algo, I wasn't even aware about it :)

Answer (score 3):

> is there any way for me to make this code work?

"What about implementing your own `atoint128_t` ?" [@Marian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608424/atoi-for-int128-t-type/45619499#comment78175593_45608424)

---

It is not to hard to roll your own `atoint128_t()`.

Points to consider.

1. There is 0 or 1 more representable negative value than positive values.  Accumulating the value using negative numbers provides more range.
2. Overflow is not defined for `atoi()`. Perhaps provide a capped value and set `errno`?  Detecting potential OF prevents UB.
3. `__int128_t` constants need careful code to form correctly.
4. How to handle unusual input?  `atoi()` is fairly loose and made sense years ago for speed/size, yet less UB is usually desired these days.  Candidate cases: `""`, `" "`, `"-"`, `"z"`, `"+123"`, `"999..many...999"`, `"the min int128"`, `"locale_specific_space" + " 123"` or even non-*string* `NULL`.
5. Code to do `atoi()` and `atoint128_t()` need only vary on the type, range, and names.  The algorithm is the same.

   ```
   #if 1
     #define int_t __int128_t
     #define int_MAX (((__int128_t)0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF << 64) + 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
     #define int_MIN (-1 - int_MAX)
     #define int_atoi atoint128_t
   #else
     #define int_t int
     #define int_MAX INT_MAX
     #define int_MIN INT_MIN
     #define int_atoi int_atoi
   #endif
   ```

Sample code:  Tailor as needed.  Relies on C99 or later `negative/positive` and `%` functionality.

```
int_t int_atoi(const char *s) {
  if (s == NULL) {  // could omit this test
    errno = EINVAL;
    return 0;
  }
  while (isspace((unsigned char ) *s)) {  // skip same leading white space like atoi()
    s++;
  }
  char sign = *s;  // remember if the sign was `-` for later
  if (sign == '-' || sign == '+') {
    s++;
  }

  int_t sum = 0;
  while (isdigit((unsigned char)*s)) {
    int digit = *s - '0';
    if ((sum > int_MIN/10) || (sum == int_MIN/10 && digit <= -(int_MIN%10))) {
      sum = sum * 10 - digit;  // accumulate on the - side
    } else {
      sum = int_MIN;
      errno = ERANGE;
      break; // overflow
    }
    s++;
  }

  if (sign != '-') {
    if (sum < -int_MAX) {
      sum = int_MAX;
      errno = ERANGE;
    } else {
      sum = -sum;  // Make positive
    }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

---

As [@Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608424/atoi-for-int128-t-type/45619499#comment78177533_45608424) commented about the lack of overflow detection, etc.  Modeling the string-->int128 after `strtol()` is a better idea.

For simplicity, consider `__128_t strto__128_base10(const char *s, char *endptr);`

This answer all ready handles overflow and flags `errno` like `strtol()`.  Just need a few changes:

```
  bool digit_found = false;
  while (isdigit((unsigned char)*s)) { 
    digit_found = true;  

      // delete the `break` 
      // On overflow, continue looping to get to the end of the digits.
      // break;


  // after the `while()` loop:
  if (!digit_found) {  // optional test
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  if (endptr) {
    *endptr = digit_found ? s : original_s;
  }
```

A full `long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);` like functionality would also handle other bases with special code when `base` is `0` or `16`.  [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608424/atoi-for-int128-t-type/45619499?noredirect=1#comment78200809_45619499)

Answer (score 2):

The C Standard does not mandate support for 128-bit integers.

Yet they are commonly supported by modern compilers: both `gcc` and `clang` support the types `__int128_t` and `__uint128_t`, but surprisingly still keep `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` limited to 64 bits.

Beyond the basic arithmetic operators, there is not much support for these large integers, especially in the C library: no `scanf()` or `printf()` conversion specifiers, etc.

Here is an implementation of `strtoi128()`, `strtou128()` and `atoi128()` that is consistent with the C Standard's `atoi()`, `strtol()` and `strtoul()` specifications.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Change these typedefs for your local flavor of 128-bit integer types */
typedef __int128_t i128;
typedef __uint128_t u128;

static int strdigit__(char c) {
    /* This is ASCII / UTF-8 specific, would not work for EBCDIC */
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ? c - '0'
        :  (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ? c - 'a' + 10
        :  (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? c - 'A' + 10
        :  255;
}

static u128 strtou128__(const char *p, char **endp, int base) {
    u128 v = 0;
    int digit;

    if (base == 0) {    /* handle octal and hexadecimal syntax */
        base = 10;
        if (*p == '0') {
            base = 8;
            if ((p[1] == 'x' || p[1] == 'X') && strdigit__(p[2]) < 16) {
                p += 2;
                base = 16;
            }
        }
    }
    if (base < 2 || base > 36) {
        errno = EINVAL;
    } else
    if ((digit = strdigit__(*p)) < base) {
        v = digit;
        /* convert to unsigned 128 bit with overflow control */
        while ((digit = strdigit__(*++p)) < base) {
            u128 v0 = v;
            v = v * base + digit;
            if (v < v0) {
                v = ~(u128)0;
                errno = ERANGE;
            }
        }
        if (endp) {
            *endp = (char *)p;
        }
    }
    return v;
}

u128 strtou128(const char *p, char **endp, int base) {
    if (endp) {
        *endp = (char *)p;
    }
    while (isspace((unsigned char)*p)) {
        p++;
    }
    if (*p == '-') {
        p++;
        return -strtou128__(p, endp, base);
    } else {
        if (*p == '+')
            p++;
        return strtou128__(p, endp, base);
    }
}

i128 strtoi128(const char *p, char **endp, int base) {
    u128 v;

    if (endp) {
        *endp = (char *)p;
    }
    while (isspace((unsigned char)*p)) {
        p++;
    }
    if (*p == '-') {
        p++;
        v = strtou128__(p, endp, base);
        if (v >= (u128)1 << 127) {
            if (v > (u128)1 << 127)
                errno = ERANGE;
            return -(i128)(((u128)1 << 127) - 1) - 1;
        }
        return -(i128)v;
    } else {
        if (*p == '+')
            p++;
        v = strtou128__(p, endp, base);
        if (v >= (u128)1 << 127) {
            errno = ERANGE;
            return (i128)(((u128)1 << 127) - 1);
        }
        return (i128)v;
    }
}

i128 atoi128(const char *p) {
    return strtoi128(p, (char**)NULL, 10);
}

char *utoa128(char *dest, u128 v, int base) {
    char buf[129];
    char *p = buf + 128;
    const char *digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    *p = '\0';
    if (base >= 2 && base <= 36) {
        while (v > (unsigned)base - 1) {
            *--p = digits[v % base];
            v /= base;
        }
        *--p = digits[v];
    }
    return strcpy(dest, p);
}

char *itoa128(char *buf, i128 v, int base) {
    char *p = buf;
    u128 uv = (u128)v;
    if (v < 0) {
        *p++ = '-';
        uv = -uv;
    }
    if (base == 10)
        utoa128(p, uv, 10);
    else
    if (base == 16)
        utoa128(p, uv, 16);
    else
        utoa128(p, uv, base);
    return buf;
}

static char *perrno(char *buf, int err) {
    switch (err) {
    case EINVAL:
        return strcpy(buf, "EINVAL");
    case ERANGE:
        return strcpy(buf, "ERANGE");
    default:
        sprintf(buf, "%d", err);
        return buf;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[130];
    char xbuf[130];
    char ebuf[20];
    char *p1, *p2;
    i128 v, v1;
    u128 v2;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s:\n", argv[i]);
        errno = 0;
        v = atoi128(argv[i]);
        perrno(ebuf, errno);
        printf("  atoi128():   %s  0x%s  errno=%s\n",
               itoa128(buf, v, 10), utoa128(xbuf, v, 16), ebuf);
        errno = 0;
        v1 = strtoi128(argv[i], &p1, 0);
        perrno(ebuf, errno);
        printf("  strtoi128(): %s  0x%s  endptr:\"%s\"  errno=%s\n",
               itoa128(buf, v1, 10), utoa128(xbuf, v1, 16), p1, ebuf);
        errno = 0;
        v2 = strtou128(argv[i], &p2, 0);
        perrno(ebuf, errno);
        printf("  strtou128(): %s  0x%s  endptr:\"%s\"  errno=%s\n",
               utoa128(buf, v2, 10), utoa128(xbuf, v2, 16), p2, ebuf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```